# Can trains use tram tracks in cities:skylines?

Tags: cities-skylines

I remember as a child seeing in my home town a train that was running down the street in the industrial area. Is this possible for trains to use tram street tracks?

Comment: Did you really see a train running on tram tracks?  A lot of industrial areas have train tracks which trams don't run on.

Comment: That is a thing. A number of US light rail systems get used by freight trains at night (San Diego; Trenton RiverLine, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

**No**, at the moment when writing this answer, trains will not run over tram/street tracks.

However, if you want to create that illusion/something similar you could try to use [**Anarchy mod**](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1844442251) which enables to lay down the train tracks over the road/road network over the train tracks.